# Calculating Percentages in R with NA's in same Column?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, percentage

I have the below data frame, which contains a NA value, I would like to create a new column called Percentages so df$percentages, so that it works as the percentage of each number in the value column divided by the total figure

```
        Country Information Value percentage
1      UK        Cars    50       0.50
2      UK       Sheep    20       0.20
3      UK        Cats    15       0.15
4      UK        Dogs    10       0.10
5      UK       Shoes     5       0.05
6      UK        Hats     NA       NA (or 0 or NULL)
7   Total               100       1.00
```

Any ideas on how to create that percentage column?

I have tried all different things but no solution!

Any help thankful for!

Comment: `df$percentage <- df$value/sum(df$value, na.rm = T)`

Comment: not quite, still getting large values that are not percentages - any ideas?

Comment: Do you have negative values in your dataset ? Because `sum(df$value)` should always be higher or equal to any value of `df$value` if values are positive.

Comment: values are what is in dataframe nothing negative but i am getting the value for example of the number 50 as 0.25? which is in correct?

Comment: That's because you are counting "Total" in your sum, so you are dividing 50 by 50+20+15+10+5+100 = 200 instead of 100. I provided the generic solution. Exclude the last line from your dataset.

Comment: how does one exclude the last line from the dataset when calculating this sum? Sorry i was not clearer previously i should have been - thanks

Comment: Updated my answer according to this point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
    df$percentage<-c(df[1:nrow(df)-1,"Value"]/sum(df[1:nrow(df)-1,"Value"],na.rm = T),1)
df
  Country Value percentage
1      UK    50       0.50
2      UK    20       0.20
3      UK    15       0.15
4      UK    10       0.10
5      UK     5       0.05
6      UK    NA         NA
7   Total   100       1.00
```

My input:

```
    df<-data.frame(Country=c("UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","UK","Total"),Value=c(50,20,15,10,5,NA,100))
```

Note: Updated using info in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Based on what was said in the comments, I will give you an extended solution (mine was similar to @Terru_theTerror).

- Define the range that defines the total, either by assuming that the last line is the total, or that the sum of every line *except* the last one gives the total.
- Divide your values by this total.

Translated in R, that gives.

```
total <- df$Value[nrow(df)] # or total <- sum(df$Value[1:(nrow(df)-1)], na.rm = T)
df$percentage <- df$Value/total
```